# django form populate request.POST instance if form is invalid

Tags: python, django

I have a student application form, and upon user form submission, if there are errors in the form (for example, telephone number keyed in wrongly), i want django to populate the form with the previous `POST` data.

If i'm not mistaken, I need to use `instance` to achieve this. But I am not sure how to get this to work.

**views.py**

```
def add_new_student(request):

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        lesson_plans = LessonPlans.objects.all()
        if 'submit_new_student' in request.POST:
            form = NewStudentForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                #todo: add cleaned data
                form.save()  # save into DB
            else:  # this is where form is not valid, and where the POST data should fill up the form with the previous `post` data.
                form = NewStudentForm(request.POST, instance=form)
        else:
            form = NewStudentForm()
        args = {
            'form': form,
            'lesson_plans': lesson_plans
        }
        return render(request, 'static/html/new_student.html', args)
```

The `trace error` that I receive is `'ModelFormOptions' object has no attribute 'concrete_fields'`

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

---

**Update**

**forms.py**

```
class NewStudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Student
        fields = [
            'first_name', 'last_name', 'DOB', 'residential_address',
            'medical_history', 'preferred_doctor',
            'parent1_first_name', 'parent1_last_name', 'relationship1_to_student', 'parent1_contact_number',
            'parent1_contact_email',
            'parent2_first_name', 'parent2_last_name', 'relationship2_to_student', 'parent2_contact_number',
            'parent2_contact_email',
            'emergency_contact_name', 'emergency_contact_number',
            'deregistration_date', 'proficiency_level'
        ]


class NewLessonPlansForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = LessonPlans
        fields = ['level', 'lesson', 'description']
```

Comment: Hi Jake, hopefully answer below helps. Let me know some of your form fields and I’ll be able to give you a specific answer for your problem.

Comment: Hi Jake - Amar’s solution is perfectly valid (however, if you want only the valid fields to pull through then my solution below will help). Depends how elegant a solution you want :)

Comment: Hi Micheal, I've updated my question to include the form fields. :)

Comment: Hi Jake - so did the below solution help you out at all - although the second answer claims you've made a simply mistake I think that my solution of only repopulate the fields that were correct make sense. You can then add some custom validation error messages to this field for extra UI/UX experience. Hopefully that makes sense! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redisplaying the form with the POST data is the *default* thing to do. You *prevent* it with your first `else` block. Remove that.

```
    if 'submit_new_student' in request.POST:
        form = NewStudentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('...')
        # no else; invalid form is automatically passed into args below
    else:
        form = NewStudentForm()
    args = {
        'form': form,
        'lesson_plans': lesson_plans
    }
    return render(request, 'static/html/new_student.html', args)
```

Comment: This is the default solution - but won't work so well if you wanted to only repopulate the fields that *were* valid, it will repopulate all fields even if they are not valid. UI/UX would dictate that the invalid fields be sent back as blank with a field error message to accompany it. I'm hoping you didn't downvote my above answer without adding a relevant comment before doing so.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I did not know that redisplaying the errored POST is the default thing django will do. I replaced my `html` with `{{ form.as_p}}` and did a quick sample, and it turns out to be the case... Which could mean that it is something within my `html` that is preventing the redisplay from happening...

Answer (score 0):

There’s a few ways you can do this:

Store the posted data into the context and return this to the page on an unsuccessful submission, making sure you handle this on the template side. You can do this using something like:

```
form = ContactForm(initial={'subject': 'Hi there!'})
```

What can also do with this built in Django solution is check if the data “has changed” from this initial state, throwing an error if not.

However, if you want all of the data back, rather than specific fields that are valid, simply use:

```
form = ContactForm(request.POST)
```

So provided you have their previous answers stored in the `request.POST` object you can then set the initial value every time they are unsuccessful.

Reference here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/api/#s-dynamic-initial-values

Or...you can use local storage. Store their values in local storage and whenever they return back, even days later (provided they haven’t refreshed their browser cache) you can grab and use their previously stored answers.

---

Specific to your setup, you could use something like:

```
def add_new_student(request):

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        lesson_plans = LessonPlans.objects.all()
        if 'submit_new_student' in request.POST:
            form = NewStudentForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                #todo: add cleaned data
                form.save()  # save into DB
            else:  # this is where form is not valid, and where the POST data should fill up the form with any combination of validated data from the previous `post` data.
                data = {
                   'first_name': request.POST.get('first_name'), 
                   'last_name': request.POST.get('last_name')
                }
                form = ContactForm(data, initial=data)
        else:
            form = NewStudentForm()
        args = {
            'form': form,
            'lesson_plans': lesson_plans
        }
        return render(request, 'static/html/new_student.html', args)
```

With the above data and initial values set, you can then also check if the form has changed on submission and if not, throw back another custom error:

```
if form.has_changed():
   # do something here
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Micheal. Are you saying that, I store the `request.POST` information in a variable, (in your example, `f`) and then upload it back to the `instance`? `form = NewStudentForm(request.POST, instance=f)`?

Comment: Hi Jake - could well be, maybe debug by using just the default blank {{ form }} first, to see if everything is working server side, then work on things client side?

Comment: Hmm, I responded before you edited your answer. Sorry about that. Let me take a look and try it out! :)

Comment: *I've also added a method specific to your question which may hopefully work.

Comment: Thanks MIchael, but Daniel's answer helped me to realise what i'm doing wrong in my code.